# ng-show not updating DOM element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to switch ng-show value dynamically.

I have a controller with two methods, one to show, one to hide:

```
var HeaderCtrl = this;

HeaderCtrl.HelpButtonVisible = "false";

HeaderCtrl.HideHelpButton = function() {

    HeaderCtrl.HelpButtonVisible = "false";
}

HeaderCtrl.ShowHelpButton = function() {

    HeaderCtrl.HelpButtonVisible = "true";  
}
```

This is the button that starts as hidden. It is also used to call the method that will hide itself:

```
<button id="help-button" ng-show="{{HelpButtonVisible}}" class="button button-stable icon-left ion-information-circled" 
     ui-sref="login" ng-click="HeaderCtrl.HideHelpButton()">Help</button>
```

This is the button with the method supposed to show:

`<button id="login-button" class="col button button-positive button-small" ng-click="HeaderCtrl.ShowHelpButton()" ui-sref="main">Log in</button>`

ng-show is update to true when I click the button above, still, the help button does not show up.

Why? I tried everything, `$scope.$apply`, `$scope.$digest`, tried calling the object without the `{{ }}`, nothing works.

Edit:

Full controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller("HeaderCtrl", function( ) {

    var HeaderCtrl = this;

    HeaderCtrl.HelpButtonVisible = false;

    HeaderCtrl.HideHelpButton = function() {

        HeaderCtrl.HelpButtonVisible = false;
    }

    HeaderCtrl.ShowHelpButton = function() {

        HeaderCtrl.HelpButtonVisible = true;    
    }
})
```

Comment: These attributes and functions should be on your `$scope` object to be accessible in the view

Comment: But it works like this, `ng-show` is updated to `false` and `true`, however, the class is not... if I try to use `visible` and `hidden`, it works for `style="visiblity:{{HeaderCtrl.HelpButtonVisible}}"`

However, this is obviously not optimal. And I did try to use $scope, to no avail.

Comment: Post your full controller

Comment: use literals `false` and `true` instead of strings

Comment: @Brennan Done. As you can see, not much changed.

Comment: @akonsu Tried, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not idiomatic angular. It is important to stick to conventions when working with angular. Anything that is connected to the DOM should be attached to the `$scope` object:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller("HeaderCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.HelpButtonVisible = false;
  $scope.HideHelpButton = function() {
    $scope.HelpButtonVisible = false;
  }
  $scope.ShowHelpButton = function() {
    $scope.HelpButtonVisible = true;    
  }
});
```

View:

```
<button id="help-button"
        ng-show="HelpButtonVisible"
        class="button button-stable icon-left ion-information-circled" 
        ui-sref="login" 
        ng-click="HideHelpButton()">Help</button>
```

Comment: Welp, It finally worked... I did exactly what you did, except I had to take the quotation marks and brackets from the ngs-show value. I did try this before, but didn't try getting the brackets off, and the quotation marks too... go figure. Well, thank you.

Comment: Oh, if you could edit the `ng-show` part, that would be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using ng-model, also you cant bind to primitives like that.
controller:

```
this.HelperObj = {"ArrofHelperObjs":[/*YOUR OBJECTS HERE*/]};
this.ToggleHelpButton = function(obj){ 
     var package = this.HelperObj.ArrofHelperObjs.length;
     var handl = this.HelperObj.ArrofHelperObjs; 
     if(package == 0){
       handl.push(obj);
       return 200;
     }
     for(var x=0;x<package;x++){
        if(handl[x] == obj){
          handl.splice(x, 1);
          return 200;    
        }
        if(x == package-1){
          handl.push(obj);
          return 200;      
        }
     }
     console.log("Error: handl= "+handl);    
     console.log("Error: obj= "+obj);
     return "Error: Conditions were supposed to have been met";
     };
```

then html

```
<div ng-repeat="x in myctrl.HelperObj.ArrofHelperObjs" >
<button ng-model="x.selected" ng-click="myctrl.ToggleHelpButton(x.html); x.selected = !x.selected" ng-show="x.selected">
 {{x.html}}
</label>
</div>
```

Two thing to point out.  ng-model is how you bind to your data.  When using ng-model, DONT BIND TO PRIMITIVES.  It took me a while to get that in my head. In the example shared, my objects have the properties selected and html. ie.

```
 this. package = {"selected":"false","html":"tagone"};
```

This would work in some cases, but most of the time you are going to have more than one object. Looks like this.

```
    this. package = {"ArrayofObjects":[]};
```

inside  those brackets[] goes all your objects. Like this

```
    this. package = {"ArrayofObjects":[{"selected":"false","html":"tagone"},{"selected":"false","html":"tagtwo"}, {"selected":"false","html":"thirdtag"}   ]};
```

Once you are set up like this, make a function that alters any of those values.  That is what my ToggleHelpButton method is doing. I am changing the value of the selected property, of that element. Then in your html, use

```
<toggledelement ng-model="ctrl.package.ArrayofObjects[x].someproperty">
```

x is the index of the array of objects.
someproperty is literal selected.
you now have an element that is bound to a truthy or falsy value.  Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this to $scope

```
var app = angular.module('ido.controllers', []);

app.controller("HeaderCtrl", function($scope) {

    angular.extend($scope, {
        HelpButtonVisible: false,
        HideHelpButton: function() {
            $scope.HelpButtonVisible = false;
        },
        ShowHelpButton: function() {
            $scope.HelpButtonVisible = true;    
        }
    });
})


<button id="help-button"
        ng-show="HelpButtonVisible"
        class="button button-stable icon-left ion-information-circled" 
        ui-sref="login" 
        ng-click="HideHelpButton()">Help</button>
```

Always attach events and values to $scope. You only have access to the $scope.

When you use the scope, there is never any need to use .$digest() or .$apply(). Only when you break out of the $scope.